# How can I simplify this awful code?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm a newb to programming and have some problems simplifying my code. I have no problem with the parts preceding this, just need to know how I can simplify this code. I'd like the code below to also plot for 12,18,20,27, and 28, in the place of "11".
I'd appreciate any help greatly!

```
simrecno1inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no1)[0]
simrecno2inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no2)[0]
simrecno3inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no3)[0]
simrecno4inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no4)[0]
simrecno5inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no5)[0]

simrecno7inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no7)[0]
simrecno8inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no8)[0]
simrecno9inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no9)[0]
simrecno10inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no10)[0]
simrecno11inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no11)[0]
simrecno12inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no12)[0]
simrecno13inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no13)[0]
simrecno14inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no14)[0]
simrecno15inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no15)[0]
simrecno16inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no16)[0]
simrecno17inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no17)[0]
simrecno18inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no18)[0]
simrecno19inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no19)[0]
simrecno20inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no20)[0]
simrecno21inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no21)[0]
simrecno22inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no22)[0]
simrecno23inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no23)[0]
simrecno24inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no24)[0]
simrecno25inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no25)[0]
simrecno26inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no26)[0]
simrecno27inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no27)[0]
simrecno28inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no28)[0]
simrecno29inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no29)[0]
simrecno30inds11 = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no30)[0]

recno1inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no1)[0]
recno2inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no2)[0]
recno3inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no3)[0]
recno4inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no4)[0]
recno5inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no5)[0]

recno7inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no7)[0]
recno8inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no8)[0]
recno9inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no9)[0]
recno10inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no10)[0]
recno11inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no11)[0]
recno12inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no12)[0]
recno13inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no13)[0]
recno14inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no14)[0]
recno15inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no15)[0] 
recno16inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no16)[0]
recno17inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no17)[0]
recno18inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no18)[0]
recno19inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no19)[0]
recno20inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no20)[0]
recno21inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no21)[0] 
recno22inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no22)[0]
recno23inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no23)[0]
recno24inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no24)[0]
recno25inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no25)[0]
recno26inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no26)[0]
recno27inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no27)[0]
recno28inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no28)[0]
recno29inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no29)[0]
recno30inds11 = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no30)[0]
```

Comment: What does `[:,1]` do?

Comment: It slices the entire first row of a numpy array.

Answer (score 5):

Whatever `no1` - `no30` is, you need to put it in a sequence object, like a `list`, then loop over that sequence object to produce the output, which you will also be putting into a sequence object (in this case I think a `dict` will be best).

```
nos = [no1, no2, ..., no30]
simrecno_inds11 = {}
recno_inds11 = {}
exclude_nums = [6]
for k, no in enumerate(nos):
    if k in exclude_nums:
        continue
    simrecno_inds11[k] = nonzero(datasim11[:,1]==no)[0]
    recno28inds11[k] = nonzero(data11[:,1]==no)[0]
```

Now instead of accessing `simrecno17inds11`, you will access `simrecno_inds11[17]`, and so forth.

Comment: Changed the output from list ==> dict, since the indices are non-sequential.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your "simrecnoXXindsYY" variables can be represented in a 2D array `simrec[n, i]` (n->no, i->inds). In the same way "recnoXXindsYY" can become just `rec[n,i]`. Finally "noXX" can be a 1D array `no[n]`. So your assignments have the form:

```
simrec[n, i] = nonzero(datasim[i][:,1]==no[n])[0]
rec[n, i] = nonzero(data[i][:,1]==no[n])[0]
```

So you would need to cycle for all possible values of `n`(nos) and `i`(indexes).

```
indexes = [11, 12, 18, 20, 27, 28]
nos = range(1,31)

for i in index:
    for n in nos:
        simrec[n, i] = nonzero(datasim[i][:,1]==no[n])[0]
        rec[n, i] = nonzero(data[i][:,1]==no[n])[0]
```

Comment: It's giving me an invalidindex error for the line                  simrec[n, i] = nonzero(datasim[i][:,1]==no[n])[0]

Comment: @boson, you have to debug, insert `print n` and `print i` in the loop and look why the index out is of bound.

Comment: It's only printing 1 and 11.

Comment: @boson, sorry I don't know if you placed your print before or after the assignments, I dont know what error you got, I don't know how your data looks->I can't help you debug via SO comments. My advice is, make a new question, paste my code, give a link to a sample of your data(dropbox, gist, whatever), describe your error, and you will get all your problems solved in no time.